# YII get request body in REST GET request

Tags: php, rest, yii

I am making a RESTful API in Yii 1.1.10. In `POST` request I can get parameters from request body using

```
$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
```

Although it might not be the ideal solution in Yii. But I am not able to get body parameters in `GET` REST request. I understand that for GET in REST, parameters should be sent in the URL  but I want to get encoded data from body.

Comment: @Sergey How to get body parameters in `REST` `GET` request?

Comment: I think you not able do it.

Comment: you might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/720508) if you haven't already

Answer (score 4):

In Yii there is a very usefull class ChttpRequest, you should checkout [CHttpRequest->getRawBody()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getRawBody-detail)

Edit: to actually use it in the app use : **Yii::app()->request->getRawBody()**